# How to test user's optional information from Firebase with Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, pytest, pyrebase

I've enabled anonymous sign-in method on Firebase, so I have some information in my User collection that aren't required.
I wannt to know how do I test using pytest and parametrize.

My Users collection  will look like this:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "" || null,
            "email": "" || null,
            "password": "" || null,
            "birthdate": Long/Number || null,
            "parents_contact": "" || null,
        }
    ]
}
```

Only the id is required in the anonymous sign-in method.

I tought write something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "id, data, status_code",
    [
        [1, {}, 200],
        [1, {"name": "John"}, 200],
        [1, {"name": "John", "email": "john@mail.com"}, 200],
        [1, {"name": "John", "email": "john@mail.com", "password": "john123"}, 200],
        ...
    ],
)
```

Is this the right way to use pytest and `parametrize`?

Comment: I mean it looks right. Does it work?

Comment: I haven't tested yet because of some problems I'm facing with another part of the code, but I will do it as soon as possible and will post here. I'm new with pytest, so I wanted to know if I'm in the right path. Thanks.